# Installing the Windows IoT Core Project Templates generates an exception when I create a new project on visual Studio 2015, OS Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iot, windows-10-iot-core

Installing the [Windows IoT Core Project Templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55b357e1-a533-43ad-82a5-a88ac4b01dec) generates an exception when I create a new project on visual Studio 2015, OS Windows 7.

The error message is "this template attempted to load component assembly microsoft.visualstudio.universal.templatewizard"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put another way, you need to do this development on a Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 1):

The windows IoT templates require the win 10 tools. You can find more information on them here:

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads